# How to transfer a photo from one viewcontroller to a UIImageView of another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a tableview, when I click on a cell, I would like to transfer a photo to another ViewController and place it right away in UIImageView

Photo transfer

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)  {

    if segue.identifier == "segue" {

        if let detail = segue.destination as? DetailViewController  {

            detail.PhotoProfile = selectedImage

        }
    }
}
```

on the second view so

```
@IBOutlet weak var PhotoProfile: UIImageView!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destination controller's view is not loaded in `prepare(for:)`, It's not the best practice of passing data between controllers but you can make sure that view is loaded before touching any if it's subviews using outlets:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)  {

    if segue.identifier == "segue" {

        if let detail = segue.destination as? DetailViewController  {
            detail.loadViewIfNeeded()
            detail.PhotoProfile = selectedImage
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's bad form to be touching another viewController's outlets.  You should keep all control of the outlets in a single viewController.  Pass the image to the viewController and let it control its own subviews as shown in the duplicate answer.

Comment: I know. Answer updated mentioning that. Thank's for your care. @vacawama